# How can I de-select recyclerView Item onSwiped?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-swipe

I have a fragment with a recyclerView.

[image: 1]

A user is allowed to delete an exercise `logEntry` by swiping right.

[image: 2]

A user can also update a `logEntry` by clicking on the recyclerView item.
(This highlights the current selected item green, hides the clear button and converts the save button to an update button.)

[image: 3]

To deselect the item , the user can click on the recyclerView a second time.

[image: 4]

Unfortunately, if a user was to select an item and then decides to swipe to delete an item, the recyclerView item which takes the same position as the originally selected item is remains highlighted green.

When a user swipes to delete an item, I would like the background of all recyclerView items to be reset to grey.

How could this be done?

**Relevant Fragment Code**

OnExerciseClicked

```
@Override
    public void onExerciseClicked(int position) {
        if (recyclerItemClicked == false) {
            saveBtn.setText("Update");
            clearBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerItemClicked = true;
            double selectedWeight = adapter.getWeight(position);
            String selectedWeightString = Double.toString(selectedWeight);
            editTextWeight.setText(selectedWeightString);

            int selectedReps = adapter.getReps(position);
            String selectedRepsString = Integer.toString(selectedReps);
            editTextReps.setText(selectedRepsString);

        } else {
            clearBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            saveBtn.setText("Save");
            recyclerItemClicked = false;
        }
    }
```

OnSwiped

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

            int logID = allExercises.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getLog_id();
            logViewModel.deleteByID(logID);
            clearBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            saveBtn.setText("Save");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
```

**Adapter**

```
public class CompletedExercisesListAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private OnExerciseClickListener onExerciseClickListener;
    private List<Log_Entries> allCompletedExercises = new ArrayList<>();
    private int adapterPos = -1;

    public boolean flag = false;

    public CompletedExercisesListAdapter2(ArrayList<Log_Entries> allCompletedExercises, OnExerciseClickListener onExerciseClickListener) {
        this.allCompletedExercises = allCompletedExercises;
        this.onExerciseClickListener = onExerciseClickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view;

        if (viewType == 0) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_completed_exercise_item, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolderOne(view, onExerciseClickListener);
        }

        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.completed_exercise_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolderTwo(view, onExerciseClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
            ViewHolderOne viewHolderOne = (ViewHolderOne) holder;

            if (adapterPos == position) {
                viewHolderOne.relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#567845"));
            } else {
                viewHolderOne.relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.dark_grey);
            }

            viewHolderOne.textViewExerciseName.setText(String.valueOf(allCompletedExercises.get(position).getChildExerciseName()));
            //viewHolderOne.textViewSetNumber.setText(String.valueOf(allCompletedExercises.get(position).getSet_number()));
            viewHolderOne.textViewSetNumber.setText(String.valueOf(viewHolderOne.getAdapterPosition() + 1));
            viewHolderOne.textViewWeight.setText(String.valueOf(allCompletedExercises.get(position).getTotal_weight_lifted()));
            viewHolderOne.textViewReps.setText(String.valueOf(allCompletedExercises.get(position).getReps()));

        } else if (getItemViewType(position) == 1) {
            ViewHolderTwo viewHolderTwo = (ViewHolderTwo) holder;

            if (adapterPos == position) {
                viewHolderTwo.relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#567845"));
            } else {
                viewHolderTwo.relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.dark_grey);
            }
            //  viewHolderTwo.textViewSetNumber.setText(String.valueOf(allCompletedExercises.get(position).getSet_number()));
            viewHolderTwo.textViewSetNumber.setText(String.valueOf(viewHolderTwo.getAdapterPosition() + 1));
            viewHolderTwo.textViewWeight.setText(String.valueOf(allCompletedExercises.get(position).getTotal_weight_lifted()));
            viewHolderTwo.textViewReps.setText(String.valueOf(allCompletedExercises.get(position).getReps()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return allCompletedExercises.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        // if list is sorted chronologically
        if (position == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (allCompletedExercises.get(position).getChildExerciseName().equals(allCompletedExercises.get(position - 1).getChildExerciseName())) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    class ViewHolderOne extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView textViewExerciseName;
        private TextView textViewSetNumber;
        private TextView textViewWeight;
        private TextView textViewReps;

        OnExerciseClickListener mOnExerciseClickListener;

        private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

        public ViewHolderOne(@NonNull View itemView, OnExerciseClickListener onExerciseClickListener) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewExerciseName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_ExerciseName3);
            textViewSetNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_Set_Number56);
            textViewWeight = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_weight78);
            textViewReps = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_repss0);
            mOnExerciseClickListener = onExerciseClickListener;
            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.exercise_item_relative);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onExerciseClickListener.onExerciseClicked(getAdapterPosition());
            if (flag) {
                adapterPos = -1;
                flag = false;
            } else {
                adapterPos = getAdapterPosition();
                flag = true;
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    class ViewHolderTwo extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView textViewSetNumber;
        private TextView textViewWeight;
        private TextView textViewReps;
        OnExerciseClickListener mOnExerciseClickListener;
        private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

        public ViewHolderTwo(@NonNull View itemView, OnExerciseClickListener onExerciseClickListener) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewSetNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_Set_Number);
            textViewWeight = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_weight);
            textViewReps = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_repss);
            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.exercise_item_rel);
            mOnExerciseClickListener = onExerciseClickListener;
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onExerciseClickListener.onExerciseClicked(getAdapterPosition());

            if (!flag) {
                adapterPos = getAdapterPosition();
                flag = true;
            } else {
                adapterPos = -1;
                flag = false;
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public interface OnExerciseClickListener {
        void onExerciseClicked(int position);
    }
    public double getWeight(int position) {
        double weight = allCompletedExercises.get(position).getTotal_weight_lifted();
        return weight;
    }
    public int getReps(int position) {
        int reps = allCompletedExercises.get(position).getReps();
        return reps;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using a library like Groupie to abstract away the complicated state management of RecyclerView. Otherwise you'll find this imperative style quickly becomes unmaintainable. The future is declarative UI (Compose etc). This way it is much easier to keep track of *Items* rather than positions.

It's quite hard to follow your code (you should use descriptive names for things, like `isSelected` instead of `flag`). However I think your problem lies in your bind function not returning false here:

`if (adapterPos == position)`

after you swipe. Use break points to work out why